# Custom child command in cypress doesn't perform click

Tags: cypress

**Background:**

I'm writing test automation for a React web application, using Cypress. In the application I have a dialog box in which there are elements I need to click. When I try to click any of these elements normally, Cypress gives me an error that the element in not visible `because its content is being clipped by one of its parent elements, which has a CSS property of overflow: 'hidden', 'scroll' or 'auto'`. Because these DOM elements are generated by some 3rd party React components, I cannot change this, and the only way I can work-around it is to use `{force:true}` in the `click` command.

**The problem:**

Because I have few of these elements and in order to keep the DRY principle, I wanted to create a custom child command named `forceClick` that simply wraps `subject.click({force:true})`. However, for some reason, when I do that, Cypress does not perform the `click` command at all!

Note: For debugging purposes I added a `cy.log` command to the custom command as well, and strangely enough, I see that this `log` command *is* executed and only the `click` command doesn't.

Here's the code:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('forceClick', {prevSubject:'element'}, subject => {
    cy.log('forceClick was called!');
    subject.click({force:true})});
```

And inside my test I have the following line:

```
cy.get("[data-test='panel-VALUES']").forceClick();
```

Note that if I change it to the following line, it works as expected:

```
cy.get("[data-test='panel-VALUES']").click({force:true});
```

Any idea why the click command isn't executed by the `forceClick` custom command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, you just missed that you have to `wrap` the `subject` if you want to work with it.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('forceClick', {prevSubject: 'element'}, (subject, options) => {
  // wrap the existing subject and do something with it
  cy.wrap(subject).click({force:true})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I never saw a solution with `subject.click({force:true})`, I'm not saying it won't work, but I just never saw it before. What works anyway is this:

Custom command:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('forceClick', {prevSubject:'element'}, subject => {
  cy.log('forceClick was called!');
  cy.get(subject)
    .click({force:true})});
}
```

Test step:

```js
cy.forceClick('[data-test="panel-VALUES"]');
```

If you only use the forceClick you could even shorten it further to this:

Custom command:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('forceClick', {prevSubject:'element'}, subject => {
  cy.log('forceClick was called!');
  cy.get(`[data-test=${subject}]`)
    .click({force:true})});
}
```

Test step:

```js
cy.forceClick('panel-VALUES');
```

Comment: Thanks @Mr. J. for your response. However, AFAIU your solution is to use a parent command instead of a child command. While it's a possible solution, it's not what I wanted, because it's creates coupling between the 'get' and the 'click', and that's not what I wanted. Also, I'd like to **understand why** my solution doesn't work, and not only what other solution does work.

Comment: Check, I can not help you with that sadly